# Symfony, mysql, fosuserbundle: Association Mapping - OneToOne

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle.

So I have this USER and ADDRESS entities and are related one to one.
I have the User created and I want to add an Address.
In the EDIT PROFILE page I want to have a form where the User can add the Address.

Here comes the question: How can I make the Addres entity know that this new addres I'm creating is for the user that is now logged in?

This is my edit action:

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:main:profile_edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

This is the user Entity (it has all the setters and getters):

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=2)
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=2)
 */
protected $lastName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
protected $isActive;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Phaddress", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $phaddress;
```

and this is the address entity (phaddres):

```
class Phaddress
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="address_first")
 */
protected $addressfirst;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="address_second")
 */
protected $address_second;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="city")
 */
protected $city;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="state")
 */
protected $state;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(max = 5)
 * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="integer")
 */
protected $zip;

/**
 * @Assert\Country();
 * @ORM\Column(name="country")
 */
protected $country;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(min = 8, max = 20, minMessage = "min_lenght", maxMessage = "max_lenght")
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\(0\)[0-9]*$", message="number_only")
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_cel")
 */
protected $phone_cel;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(min = 8, max = 20, minMessage = "min_lenght", maxMessage = "max_lenght")
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\(0\)[0-9]*$", message="number_only")
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_nb")
 */
protected $phone_nb;

/**
 * One Cart has One Customer.
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="phaddress")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

and this is the form in .twig file:

```
 {{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'attr': { 'class': 'form-group' } }) }}
   {{ form_row(form.username, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'margin-bottom: 0.7em' } } ) }}
   {{ form_row(form.firstName, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'margin-bottom: 0.7em' } } ) }}
   {{ form_row(form.lastName, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'margin-bottom: 0.7em' } } ) }}
   {{ form_row(form.email, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'margin-bottom: 0.7em' } } ) }}
   {{ form_row(form.current_password, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'margin-bottom: 0.7em' } } ) }}
   {{ form_row(form.phaddress.zip, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'margin-bottom: 0.7em' } } ) }}
   <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" class="btn btn-success" />
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

No code at all doesn't help... We have no idea on how you display your form...

Why don't you just edit your user entity to hold user address?

Either way, a wild guess would be like this in twig:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Entity:edit', { 'userId': user.id })) }}
```

Modify your controller `editAction()` to `editAction($userId)`, and look at [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html)